# Not receiving latest data using Npgsql LISTEN/NOTIFY

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, signalr, npgsql

I'm using .NET Core app with a PostgreSQL database (with Npgsql) combined with SignalR to receive real-time data and latest data entries. However, I am not receiving the latest entry, and sometimes the  `Clients.All.SendAsync` method sends more than one entry to the client. Here is my code:

**Hub method that sends new data to client:**

```
public async Task SendForexAsync(string name)
    {
        var product = GetForex(name);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("CurrentData", product);
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ApplicationDbContext.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN new_forex", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Notification += async (o, e) =>
            {
                var newProduct = GetForex(name);
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("NewData", newProduct);
            };

            while (true)
            {
                await conn.WaitAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Console app that periodically polls for new data from an API:**

```
var addedStocksDJI = FetchNewStocks("DJI");
if (addedStocksAAPL > 0 || addedStocksDJI > 0)
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ApplicationDbContext.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("NOTIFY new_stocks", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The other code of the app is most definitely correct because I was receiving new and correct data before I tried implementing the LISTEN/NOTIFY feature. But now, I get one (or more) of entries of `newProduct` on my client, but it is the "old" product, that is, the database does not query and send the latest entries, but only the old ones via SignalR. When I refresh the page manually, the new data is correctly displayed, though.

I believe it has something to do with a single connection being open so I constantly receive only the "old" set of data, but even if that is the case, I am unable to figure out why I sometimes get more than one packet of data, even though I am only trying to send one, and I am calling `NOTIFY` only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Hopefully this will help someone else who gets stuck with this in the future!

The issue was that I was declaring my `dbContext` via .NET Core's dependency injection in my `Hub` class, which created the context only once per that class, and also because of that per page or WebSocket transaction. Which is why I was unable to get the latest data, I assume, since the `dbContext` was "old" and unaware of changes.

I fixed the problem by using a `dbContext` via the `using` scheme inside of my methods, twice in my `SendForexAsync` method (once per every call of the `GetForex` function), as well as in the `GetForex` function itself. That way, a `dbContext` is created and disposed of immediately, so the next time I poll the database for new data via the `GetForex` function (when I get a notification from the database due to the `NOTIFY` from the console app), a new instance of `dbContext` is created which can contain that new data.